# How can I label subplots a,b,c,d in plotly using Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to label subplots, similar to this:
[image]

where the labels (a), (b), etc are in the same position on the plots regardless of the scales of the plots.  In other words, it seems like a good way to specify this would be a position on the plots by inches or centimeters.  How do I do this in Python with plotly?  I've only seen ways to annotate by [plotting scatter points](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/), which seems like it will be a pain to implement with radically different scales in subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could annotate your subplots via `layout: annotations`. Setting `xref` and `yref` to [`paper`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-annotations-xref) lets you specify the `x` and `y` coordinates relative to the total plot size (the arrow needs to hidden as well via `showarrow=False`), e.g.

```
fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig['layout'].update(list(annotations=dict(
    text='(a)', 
    xref='paper', 
    x=0.1, 
    yref='paper', 
    y=0.8, 
    showarrow=False
 )))
```

The plot was created with the code below. It surely needs some more tweaking but it you'll get the idea.

[image]
A few more little things were needed to get the plot:

- Hide the subplot names via `subplot_titles=(('',) * 6)`
- Hide the scatter plot trace names via `name='', showlegend=False`
- Hide the ticklabels of the histogram via `colorbar=dict(showticklabels=False)`
- Hide one histogram colorbar via `showscale=False`

Good luck!

```
import plotly
import numpy

n = 50000 #number of random points for heatmaps/histograms

#location of the annotations
anno_x = [0.05, 0.6]
anno_y = [0.8, 0.00]

#the ranges of all subplots, [row][x, y]
row_range = list()
row_range.append([[0, 7.25], [35, 105]])
row_range.append([[25, 225], [425, 775]])
row_range.append([[0, 5.25], [-5.25, 2.75]])

#label annotations for each subplot
labels = ['(a)', '(b)', '', '', '(c)', '(d)']

#create the subplot
fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2, subplot_titles=(('',) * 6))

#assign the annotations
annotations = list()
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    if label:
        annotations.append(dict(text=label, x=anno_x[i % 2], y=anno_y[i // 3], xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=False))

    else:
        annotations.append(dict(showarrow=False, text=''))

fig['layout'].update(annotations=annotations)

#let's create some random data
trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=[i for i in range(8)],
        y=[100 - i * numpy.random.randint(7) for i in range(8)],
        name='',
        showlegend=False,
    )
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)

trace2 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=[i for i in range(8)],
        y=[100 - i * 5 + numpy.random.randint(2) for i in range(8)],
        name='',
        showlegend=False,
    )
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)

#some random points for the 1st heatmap/histogram
trace3 = plotly.graph_objs.Histogram2d(
        x=numpy.random.normal(loc=80, scale=50, size=n),
        y=numpy.random.normal(loc=525, scale=200, size=n),
        autobinx=False,
        autobiny=False,
        xbins=dict(start=row_range[1][0][0], end=row_range[1][0][1], size=5),
        ybins=dict(start=row_range[1][1][0], end=row_range[1][1][1], size=5),
        colorbar=dict(showticklabels=False)
    )
fig.append_trace(trace3, 2, 1)

trace4 = plotly.graph_objs.Histogram2d(
        x=numpy.random.normal(loc=50, scale=100, size=n),
        y=numpy.random.normal(loc=550, scale=200, size=n),
        showscale=False,
        colorbar=dict(showticklabels=False)
    )
fig.append_trace(trace4, 2, 2)

trace5 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=[i for i in range(6)],
        y=[0 - i + numpy.random.rand() for i in range(6)],
        name='',
        showlegend=False,
    )
fig.append_trace(trace5, 3, 1)

trace6 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=[i for i in range(6)],
        y=[2 - i * 0.3 for i in range(6)],
        name='',
        showlegend=False,
    )
fig.append_trace(trace6, 3, 2)

for i in range(1, 7):
    fig['layout']['xaxis' + str(i)].update(range=row_range[((i - 1) // 2)][0])
    fig['layout']['yaxis' + str(i)].update(range=row_range[((i - 1) // 2)][1])

plot_url = plotly.plotly.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  It's been tough for me to find how to do simple things like this in plotly sometimes.

Comment: As another example, I can't figure out how to make a single plot out of multiple figures, each as subplots.  Seems like it should be so simple.

Comment: @wordsforthewise: just create a new question, otherwise the comments here become quite convoluted.

Comment: [I did.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096172/make-plot-out-of-multiple-plot-ly-figures-in-python?noredirect=1#comment71371658_42096172)