# Make plot out of multiple plot.ly figures in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I've made 4 figures in plot.ly, for example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y=[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
fig1 = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig2 = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig3 = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig4 = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Now I want to make a subplot, and add each figure to a quadrant of it:

```
from plotly import tools
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2)
```

but I don't see any `fig.append_fig()` method, only an `append_trace()` method.  Is there no easy way to drop in a figure into a subplot in plot.ly?

Comment: What's the disadvantage of `append_trace()`?

Comment: It's just more work.  I made the plots individually first, then found out there's no way to join them into a set of 4 plots.  Going to try to export them as static images and join them with openCV or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think `fig['data'] += data` can help.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y1 = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
x2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
y2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

data1 = [go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1), go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2)]
data2 = [go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1, xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2'), go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2, xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2')]
data3 = [go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1, xaxis='x3', yaxis='y3'), go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2, xaxis='x3', yaxis='y3')]
data4 = [go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1, xaxis='x4', yaxis='y4'), go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2, xaxis='x4', yaxis='y4')]

from plotly import tools
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2)
fig['data'] += data1
fig['data'] += data2
fig['data'] += data3
fig['data'] += data4
py.plot(fig, filename = 'basic-line')
```